# Use Azure Table SAS token to read data using Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a SAS token for the authorization header in a REST API call to Azure Tables using PowerShell. I've created a test Account SAS and tried passing the actual token value starting with the "sr=" tag and also the full URI however I'm getting the following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod :
>     AuthenticationFailed
>     Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

```
$resource = "$tableName(PartitionKey='$domain',RowKey='$apiKey')"
$tableUrl = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$resource"

$sasReadToken = "SharedAccessSignature ?sv=2017-07-29&ss=t&srt=o&sp=r&se=2019-03-07T02:37:08Z&st=2018-03-06T18:37:08Z&spr=https&sig=<removed>"

$GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')

$header = @{
    Authorization = $sasReadToken;
    'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime;
    Accept         = "application/json;odata=fullmetadata";
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tableUrl -Headers $header -Method Get -Verbose
```

While I realize there is an AzureRm module to handle some of this, I don't want to install unnecessary libraries on the host PC. Is this even possible?

NOTE: The signature has been removed in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use my SAS as part of the URI to authenticate to the storage using the following code. **Notice the SAS token is part of the $tableUri variable and not part of the header**. I also had to add the `Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'` parameter in the header otherwise I received a (415) error (Unsupported Media Type). Lastly, I had to add the `-UseBasicParsing` in PowerShell to read the data coming back.

```
function Get-MyAdvisorToken {
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [parameter()]$MyAdvisorApiKey,
    [parameter()]$DomainName
)

#retrieves SaSToken from Azure Table when supplying the API KEY and DOMAIN
$partitionKey = $DomainName #partitionKey
$rowKey = $MyAdvisorApiKey #rowKey
$sasReadToken = "?sv=2017-07-29&ss=t&srt=o&sp=r&se=2018-03-06T19:37:08Z&st=2018-03-06T18:37:08Z&spr=https&sig=<removed>"
$tableUri = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$tableName(PartitionKey='$partitionKey',RowKey='$rowKey')$sasReadToken"

$GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
$header = @{
    'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime;
    Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
}

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $tableUri -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing
$jsonResult = $result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
return $jsonResult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS Tokens are not valid in the Authorization header.  They are only valid as a collection of query string parameters.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1 for more info about Azure Storage SAS tokens.